# jQuery - Hide / Show not displaying div and showing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if someone could help me out with a bit of jquery im trying to write.

Im quite new to jQuery so this is prob something easy.

I have a div with an id of 'about-box'

I want it to slide in and out of the viewport when a menu item is pressed.

I have the following jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu-item-1 a').click(function() {
            if($('#about-box:visible').length)
                $('#about-box').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
            else
                $('#about-box').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

But i am getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `($('#about-box:visible').length)` that is not a condition

Comment: @Rafael yes it is, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/33wcn31p/

Comment: @ekad, shouldn't it be like this? 
" if ($('#about-box').is(":visible")){..." 
http://jsfiddle.net/33wcn31p/1/

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev that'll work too, but OP's problem is something else, probably related to jquery not being loaded correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is not a reason for the problem and it works but this is not correct. That is why this note is not an answer, but a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not including jQuery-UI in your page, the [show](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/) implementation you have used requires jQuery UI

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-item-1 a').click(function() {
    if ($('#about-box').stop(true, true).is(':visible')) {
      $('#about-box').hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $('#about-box').show("slide", {
        direction: "left"
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="menu-item-1"><a>menu-item-1 a</a></div>
<div id="about-box">about-box</div>
```

You can also use [jQueryUI toggle](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-item-1 a').click(function() {
    $('#about-box').toggle("slide", {
      direction: "left"
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="menu-item-1"><a>menu-item-1 a</a></div>
<div id="about-box">about-box</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

since document is for sure a good element the undefined is not on the ready
:visible looks good see here http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

So the undefined must be here $('#menu-item-1 a').click or in other code in your page or on the execution of the ready.

Try to find where . remove the if else . does the undefined throw?? if yes the  $('#menu-item-1 a') doesnt resolve.

wish it help

Answer (score -1):

try changing the selector to

```
$('#about-box').is(':visible')
```

Answer (score -2):

`$('#about-box:visible')` is a wrong selector,I think you can toggle a class on about-box  button and decide slide in or out